# React native или flutter?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter, app

Начинаем писать приложение для android and ios. Приложение типа каршэринга. После приложений будет готовиться сайт. 
Хотим работать на react native or flutter. Какой из них будет более подходящим для данной задачи?

Answer (score 4):

**Плюсы Flutter:**

- Быстрее в разработке.
- Гибче в создание дизайна (+ легко делать анимации).
- Стабильное приложение на выходе (Важно: необходимо делать relise версию, чтобы смотреть стабильность и плавность приложения).
- Отсутствие проблем сборки под iOS и Android (В RN есть проблемы с этим).
- Рендеринг одинаковый на Android и iOS (используется движок Skia, нет никакого бриджа как у RN).
- Если делать правильно, можно получить отрисовку в 60fps.
- [Flutter for Web](https://flutter.dev/web) уже в бете.

Примеры приложений: [один](https://flutter.dev/showcase), [два](https://itsallwidgets.com/).

---

**Плюсы React Native:**

- JS легче для новичка (но есть возможность написать плохой код).
- Огромное количество плагинов (Все что есть на JS, можно использовать).

---

У обоих есть проблемы в виде работы с железом: bluetooth, gps и т.д. Не очень критично, для несложных задач можно использовать.

По вашему приложению, я понимаю нужно использовать:

- Карта
- GPS
- +/- Система оплаты

А все остальное ложиться на бекенд. Я бы выбрал Flutter, он все это умеет, проблема будет только с фоновой работой приложения (если она нужна вообще).

---

[image: Сравнение React native и Flutter]

Comment: Gps and map не будут, лишь онлайн оплата.    Так же интересна дальнейшая поддержка, не будет ли сложной? Советуете flutter?

Comment: Если только оплата и по API или уже есть библиотека на pub.dev, то вообще никаких проблем на Flutter'е не будет. Главное выбрать правильную архитектуру приложения ([BLoC, Redux, MobX, MVI](http://fluttersamples.com/)).