# React native или ionic?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flutter, ionic

Стоит задача сделать приложение по функционалу похожий на aviasales, где юзер сможет сам разместить предложение и так же купить такое же предложение с возможностью оплаты онлайн. Будем делать сразу на две платформы - ios и android.
Суть - для данной задачи лучше будет react native или ionic? Или же подойдет flutter?
Если у кого есть опыт, посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Такими вопросами вы навряд-ли что-то выберете, все перечисленные технологии приведут вас к конечному результату. Но вот каков будет путь это уже другой вопрос, и чтобы получить на него ответ, вам необходимо самостоятельно попробовать их. Вы увидите разницу между технологиями, посмотрите на их возможности и особенности, а также вы поймете на какой технологии вам будет приятно писать.

---

Так как про [React native vs Flutter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1076027/react-native-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-flutter) я уже сказал свое слово, добавлю про Ionic(Cordova):

- Имеет все преимущества React native
- Гибридное приложение (По сути Web-App, которое использует WebView)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Путь меня не пугает, в любом случае конечный результат будет. Как и спрашивал, кто прошел данный путь, для более стабильного и эффективного результата какая из технологий будет более предпочтительнее? Прочитал много об этих трех технологиях, но для для данного кейса не могу найти инфо (приложение на подобие aviasales и blablacar)

Comment: Все-же попробуйте сделать какой нибудь тестовый проект (желательно с api) на всех технологиях. И поймете разницу, а также определитесь на чем будете разрабатывать ваш основной проект (+ уже как месяц прошел, можно было что-то начать делать...).

Comment: Лично я для себя выбрал Flutter, из-за его идеи и подхода (на рынке подобного не было)

Comment: @IlyasIlyas flutter однозначно, если нет опыта ни там, ни там